# php -v shows version php5.6.40 but attempting to install php7.3 shows already installed?

Tags: php, soap, virtualbox, ubuntu-server

I have a headless home server that was upgraded over the years from Ubuntu Server LTS 14.04 to 16.04 to 18.04.

I have installed VirtualBox and have also installed phpvirtualbox. In the browser when I log in to phpvirtualbox, I am greeted with this message:

> PHP does not have the SOAP extension enabled.

So I installed php-soap but I still get the message above.

My php version is:

> PHP 5.6.40-5+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)

When I thought I might upgrade to php7.3 which as far as I can see is shipped with Ubuntu LTS 18.04 I ran `sudo apt-get install php7.3` I got:

```
php7.3-common is already the newest version
(7.3.3-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1). php7.3-common set to manually
installed. php7.3-soap is already the newest version
(7.3.3-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1). php7.3-soap set to manually
installed.
```

So this confuses me because a) `php -v` shows a different version and b) it appears the php-soap for php7.3 was installed.

I don't mind either installing php-soap for php 5.6.40 or upgrading php to version 7.3.

Any way out of this mess?

Comment: CLI and web versions can be different. Load a page with `phpinfo()` in it and what do you get?

Comment: Shows: PHP Version 5.6.40-5+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

Comment: So sounds like your CLI version is newer than the module your (apache?) web server is running.